# Python3 decode doesn't work on mac

Tags: decode, python-3.4

I wrote this code:

```
'\xe4\xf6\xfc'.decode('latin1')
```

but I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I am using python 3.4 and I am using python on mac.

Comment: Nothing to do with the platform - `str.decode` doesn't exist in 3.x (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods and https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the string type does not support the `.decode()` method in Python 3. Simply prefix your string with `b`, which turns it into the `bytes` type:

```
>>> b'\xe4\xf6\xfc'.decode('latin1')
'äöü'
```